# Difference between EST and America/New_York time zones

Tags: java, calendar, timezone

Can somebody please tell, what's the difference between the following two statements:

```
TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York")
```

and

```
TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST")
```

In other words, why is EST different from America/New_York. Also in my application, to get the current time zone in US, should I use America/New_York or EST.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

EST is *half* of the New York time zone, effectively. It's *always* in standard time - it doesn't have the daylight saving part. It's not *really* a proper time zone in its own right, IMO - it's the "standard" part of a fuller time zone. When writing about a time zone which is *just* a fixed offset and not related to a particular place, I'd prefer to use "Etc/GMT+5" or something similarly obviously-fixed. (I don't generally like even "Eastern Time" and the like, as different places which observe "Eastern Time" may vary in their DST transitions. It's a bit like calling an encoding "extended ASCII"... it tells you *some* information, but not quite enough.)

So if you want to know the *actual* local time for New York at any particular instant, use America/New_York.

In general, stay away from the abbreviations. From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html):

> For compatibility with JDK 1.1.x, some other three-letter time zone IDs (such as "PST", "CTT", "AST") are also supported. However, their use is deprecated because the same abbreviation is often used for multiple time zones (for example, "CST" could be U.S. "Central Standard Time" and "China Standard Time"), and the Java platform can then only recognize one of them.

(Personally I'd also advise you to stay away from `Date` and `Calendar`, preferring to use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) wherever possible. That's a different matter though, really.)

Comment: I think suggesting it's not a proper time zone is misleading, since some timezones don't have DST/non-DST splits. Do names like EST get used for nautical timezones, or do they just use offsets?

Comment: @JamesAylett: Pass. I'd really hope not, given that they're ambiguous. (IIRC, CST is ambiguous between "Central Standard Time" and "Central Summer Time in Australia, which is particularly unhelpful - although one of those hasn't been used for many years.) Nice to see you, btw :)

Comment: @JamesAylett: I was suggesting that it's not a proper time zone not because it doesn't observe DST, but because it's clearly part of something which *does* observe DST - otherwise the "Standard" part would be redundant. Of course "GMT" becomes tricky around 1969 too, when it deviated from the not-yet-in-existence UTC :(

Comment: Yes, I know why and to that extent I entirely agree; but the existence of parts of the world where DST isn't observed feels like something worth pointing out. Of course, when you get historical, time zones are increasingly painful, DST very painful, DDST…well, doubly so.

Comment: I think the only way to make any sense of the mess that is date/time arithmetic is to enforce strict conventions.  The distinction that "New York Time" is sometimes "EDT" and sometimes "EST" means that you have to stick to the New York time zone to be unambiguous.

Comment: You can use the new Java8 date API:
java.time.LocalDate
java.time.LocalTime
java.time.LocalDateTime
java.time.ZonedDateTime

Comment: Perfect answer; exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 136):

EST is UTC - 5 hours.  America/New_York is EST in the winter and E**D**T in the summer, so right now New York is UTC - 4 hours.

Answer (score 5):

The timezone, `America/New_York` observes [two different timezone offsets](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/usa/new-york):

1. EST (winter time): has a timezone offset of `-05:00` hours
2. EDT (summer time): has a timezone offset of `-04:00` hours

[image]

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Also, quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

#### What Date-Time object should I use to adjust the offset automatically?

Use [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) which has been designed to adjust the timezone offset automatically.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");

        // Custom times
        ZonedDateTime zdtDstOn = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDate.of(2020, Month.OCTOBER, 22), LocalTime.MIN, zoneId);
        ZonedDateTime zdtDstOff = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDate.of(2020, Month.NOVEMBER, 22), LocalTime.MIN, zoneId);
        System.out.println(zdtDstOn);
        System.out.println(zdtDstOff);

        // Current time
        ZonedDateTime zdtNow = ZonedDateTime.now(zoneId);
        System.out.println(zdtNow);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-10-22T00:00-04:00[America/New_York]
2020-11-22T00:00-05:00[America/New_York]
2021-08-17T12:19:41.854781-04:00[America/New_York]
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/9gdblA)

#### Avoid using the abbreviated timezone names

The following quote from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html) states the problem clearly:

> ##### Three-letter time zone IDs
>
> For compatibility with JDK 1.1.x, some
> other three-letter time zone IDs (such as "PST", "CTT", "AST") are
> also supported. However, their use is deprecated because the same
> abbreviation is often used for multiple time zones (for example, "CST"
> could be U.S. "Central Standard Time" and "China Standard Time"), and
> the Java platform can then only recognize one of them.

#### Then, what Date-Time object should I use for a fixed timezone offset?

Use [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) for a fixed timezone offset.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZoneOffset zoneOffset = ZoneOffset.of("-04:00");

        // A custom time
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.of(LocalDate.of(2020, Month.OCTOBER, 22), LocalTime.MIN, zoneOffset);
        System.out.println(odt);

        // Current time
        OffsetDateTime odtNow = OffsetDateTime.now(zoneOffset);
        System.out.println(odtNow);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-10-22T00:00-04:00
2021-08-17T12:36:09.123599-04:00
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/iUXDJI)

**Note:** For any reason, if you need to convert an object of `OffsetDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime` to an object of `java.util.Date`, you can do so as follows:

```
Date date = Date.from(odtNow.toInstant());
```

or

```
Date date = Date.from(zdtNow.toInstant());
```

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67752047/10819573) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505173/10819573) to learn how to use `java.time` API with JDBC.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>