# Parse string to date in particular Timezone using Java

Tags: java, timezone, jodatime

Performing some operations using Java Date.
Have the following code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS";
        String d="1970-04-10 00:00:00.0";
        Date parsingDate=null;
        XMLGregorianCalendar xl=null;

        SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
        parser.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
        try {
            parsingDate=parser.parse(d);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(parsingDate);
    }
```

The output is Fri Apr 10 10:30:00 **IST** 1970.

Shouldn't this not be IST and be EST as follows
 Fri Apr 10 10:30:00 **EST** 1970.

Thanks

Comment: EST is UTC - 5 hours. America/New_York is EST in the winter and E*D*T in the summer, so right now New York is UTC - 4 hours.refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863625/difference-between-est-and-america-new-york-time-zones

Comment: When I ran your code, I had CET. Because Date does not have the notion of timezone. CET is my system timezone, which is what `toString()` uses.

Comment: FYI: Using *java.time* classes… `LocalDate.parse( "1970-04-10" ).atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ).toString()`  ➤ `1970-04-10T00:00-05:00[America/New_York]`. Search *Stack Overflow* for those classes to learn more.