# Conversion of GMT to EST gives time one hour less

Tags: java, timezone

I'm trying to convert GMT to EST a simple process , but the output of EST shows one hour less than then the current time as searched in google, Can anyone suggests me as why is that so.

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TimeZone tz=TimeZone.getDefault();
        Calendar cal=new GregorianCalendar();
        cal.setTimeZone(tz);
        Date date = cal.getTime();
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy K:mm a");
        System.out.println("GMT  TIME "+dateFormat.format(date));
        TimeZone estTime = TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST");
        dateFormat.setTimeZone(estTime);
        String submittedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

        System.out.println("EST TIME  "+submittedDate);
        }
}
```

Above example code

Comment: Your program is correct. Go to https://time.is/ru/EST

Comment: I guess this is due to daylight savings. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to use `TimeZone estTime = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York");` instead of `TimeZone estTime = TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST");`  to get the desired results.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863625/difference-between-est-and-america-new-york-time-zones

Comment: @MattJohnson Thanks for pointing