# MuleSoft Scheduler New York Time Zone

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, mule4

What is the proper notation to add the Eastern Time Zone (EST) in the United States to a MuleSoft Scheduler?

From some vague online resources, I added **America/New York** but would like to confirm.

[image]

Comment: are doing it locally? if yes then its fine but when you will deploy it on cloud hub the time zone will be ignored because if an application is running in CloudHub, the Scheduler conforms to the UTC timezone, regardless of the geographic region in which the application is running.

Comment: Mule is developed in Java, so Java timezone manages applies to using Mule standalone. Does this answer your question? [Difference between EST and America/New\_York time zones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9863625/difference-between-est-and-america-new-york-time-zones)

Comment: Also, for clarity, Eastern Time Zone and EST are different timezones. Eastern time zone covers both EST and EDT, i.e. it respects the daylight savings time and adjusts accordingly.